# Extjs4, Select grid row after reload grid

Tags: grid, extjs4

I want to select a specific row after reload my grid.
and the specific row will be different in every process. So after reload grid, I want to select the row at the once. It does not effect to select the row later.

I tried like this,

```
//i is row index No. and i value is vary.
this.getMyGrid().fireEvent('itemclick',this.getMyGrid().getView(),this.getMyGrid().store.getAt(i)); // this reload grid
this.getMyGrid().getSelectionModel().select(i);// select row
```

but **the code problem is select row before complete load grid.**

How can I run the select code after grid load complete?

Thank you.

Comment: @Expert wanna be: why don't you execute the second line in the `itemclick` event handler? You can even send the parameter `i` to that handler to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid's selection model has a method [**getLastSelected**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-getLastSelected), you can can use something like this in the grid store's `load` event handler:

```
var myGrid = this.getMyGrid(),
    selModel = myGrid.getSelectionModel();

selModel.select(selModel.getLastSelected());
```